# Notice: Undefined index: in options-framework.php

Tags: theme-options, sanitization, notices

I am generating the following notice in the options-framework.php.

Notice: Undefined index: in options-framework.php

I believe it is something to do with sanitization, but do not know how to resolve this issue.

I have the following arrays defined in options.php

```
// Pull all the custom taxonomies into an array
$options_password_taxonomies = array();
$taxonomies_password_terms_obj = get_terms('password_gallery_category');
foreach ( $taxonomies_password_terms_obj as $taxonomy) {
    if( isset( $taxonomy->term_id ) ){
        $options_password_taxonomies[$taxonomy->term_id] = $taxonomy->name;
    }
}

 // Select a Category for your Client Area
$options[] = array(
    'name' => __('Password Protected Galleries', 'shutter'),
    'desc' => __('Choose a category for password protected client galleries.', 'shutter'),
    'id' => 'client_area',
    'type' => 'select',
    'options' => $options_password_taxonomies);
```

options-framework.php

```
// For a value to be submitted to database it must pass through a sanitization filter
    if ( has_filter( 'of_sanitize_' . $option['type'] ) ) {
        $clean[$id] = apply_filters( 'of_sanitize_' . $option['type'],   $input[$id], $option );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you have an undefined array index. You can check if the array index exists with `isset()` like this:

```
if(isset($some_array[$some_index])){

}
```

So check all your arrays in the `options-framework.php` file.

You can try for example:

```
if ( isset($option['type']) && isset($input[$id]) && has_filter( 'of_sanitize_' . $option['type'] ) ) {
        $clean[$id] = apply_filters( 'of_sanitize_' . $option['type'],   $input[$id], $option );
}
```